# Не вписывается tooltip

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что не вписывается `tooltip` в блок `div`, но без блока всё ок.
Вот сам код:

```css
.containerm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(24, 33, 52, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 #3adbfd;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.containerm input[type="text"],
.containerm input[type="password"] {
  width: 315px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.inputm input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px rgba(58, 219, 253, 0.35);
}

.inputm::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f007";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 7px;
  color: #2c536c;
}

.inputm:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "\f023";
}


/* tooltip */

a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}

a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerm">
  <div id="errors"></div>
  <form id="login-form" action="/handle.php" method="POST">
    <a class="tooltips">
      <div class="inputm">
        <!--Если убрать этот блок всё будет ок, но пропадёт иконка с формы-->
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Enter your login">
      </div>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </a>
    <div class="inputm">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Пробовал решить проблему сам, понял что класс `.inputm` занимает всю ширину страницы и из-за этого tooltip смещается вверх или вниз, но никак не получилось решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переработал большую часть стилей и разметки. Результат:

```css
.containerm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(24, 33, 52, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 #3adbfd;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.containerm input[type="text"],
.containerm input[type="password"] {
  width: 315px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.inputm input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px rgba(58, 219, 253, 0.35);
}

.inputm {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.inputm::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f007";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 7px;
  color: #2c536c;
}

.inputm:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "\f023";
}

.inputm > .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.inputm:hover > .tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  right: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerm">
  <div id="errors"></div>
  <form id="login-form" action="/handle.php" method="POST">
    <div class="inputm">
      <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Enter your login">
      <span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inputm">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      <span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, сразу видно руку мастера своего дела!